# Distinguish EIdDnsResolverError of different kind

Tags: delphi, dns, indy

I am scanning for DNS servers in a local network using `TIdDNSResolver`, so the result of a DNS request is not important. I check if there is a DNS server at all.

The app should also not depend on the requested DNS record existence, so instead of an existent host it requests a knowingly non-existent name.

In this case an exception of `EIdDnsResolverError` type is being raised.

This exception could be accompanied by following error texts:

- **TimedOut** - it means that DNS server has not answered in time and we should assume that it does not exist.
- **DNS Server Reports Query Name Error** - DNS server is there
- **DNS Server Reports Query Server Error** - DNS server is there

I do not like to distinguish these errors by error text. Are there some other means of distinction?

```
function TDNSChecker.CheckServer(host: string): Boolean;
var
  dr: TIdDNSResolver;
begin
  Result := False;
  try
    dr := TIdDNSResolver.Create(nil);
    try
      dr.Host := host;
      dr.QueryType := [qtA];
      dr.WaitingTime := 1000;
      dr.Resolve('feufgzrfapoduiuzgfuzfsufseuszfu'); //knowingly non-existent name
      Result := True;
    finally
      _finished := True;
      dr.Free();
    end;
  except
    on ex: EIdDnsResolverError do
      if ex.Message <> 'TimedOut' then begin
        if (ex.Message = 'DNS Server Reports Query Name Error') or (ex.Message = 'DNS Server Reports Query Server Error') then
          Result := True
        else
          Log(host + ' - ' + ex.ClassName + ': ' + ex.Message.Replace(#13#10, ' '));
      end;
    on ex: Exception do;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: With the existing Indy code, no: there's no way of making the distinction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `TIdDNSResolver` does not currently use different exception class types for different DNS errors, it only uses `EIdDnsResolverError`.  I have [opened a ticket](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/240) in Indy's issue tracker to possibly add more error classes in a future release.

So, in the meantime, to distinguish between DNS errors, you will have to look at the exception's `Message` property.  The possible error messages are stored as resource strings in the `IdResourceStringsProtocols` unit (there are about 21 strings related to DNS errors).  Just note that some of them are formatted strings, so a simple comparison as-is will not work, you will have to use something like `TextStartsWith()` or similar to ignore any formatted portions.

On the other hand, the fact that you get an `EIdDnsResolverError` exception at all will *usually* mean you received a response from a DNS server.  You don't need to distinguish between every possible Indy DNS error to know that a DNS server exists.  Only a few `EIdDnsResolverError` errors are related to the connection itself, such as `RSDNSTimeout`, `RSTunnelConnectToMasterFailed`, etc rather than to the contents of the DNS messaging.

If you are using a version of Delphi that has the `Exception.InnerException` property available, then the `InnerException` may be set to `EIdConnectTimeout` or `EIdConnectException` when `TIdDNSResolver` uses TCP (only when `qtAXFR` or `qtIXFR` is present in the `QueryType`) instead of UDP.  There is also the possibility that the `InnerException` may be `EIdNotEnoughData`, but that would be a messaging error, not a connection error.

In your example, UDP would be used, so I think just about any `EIdDNSResolverError` error other than `RSDNSTimeout` would indicate the presence of a DNS server.